# Running load tests using MSTests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mstest, load-testing

I've been trying to get load tests to run successfully using MSTest with no luck. If I run mstest on the dll produced by my project then it doesn't find any tests, but if I try run it directly on the .loadtest file (like this link suggests https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406971.aspx) it says that it is not a valid extension.

I have been trying to get it work via a build agent as well, but at the moment both locally and on the build agent the result as just been a successful build, but not actual tests run.

edit: Just worth noting that the load test runs fine when I run it through Visual Studio

Comment: Please show the exact command line you are using to try to invoke tests on your DLL using MSTest.  NOTE: the path in the `/testcontainer:` parameter must be FULLY-QUALIFIED.

Comment: I've been using full qualified parameters, for example my last attempt at running it was:
"MSTest.exe /testcontainer:StressTesting\bin\Debug\StressTesting.dll  /testsettings:Local.testsettings"

Comment: This is the output I'm getting:
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.21005.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Local.testsettings...
Loading SDPStressTesting\bin\Debug\SDPStressTesting.dll...
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.